# How to map over setters in a functional component?

Tags: reactjs

So I have several rating options and have a separate state for each of them. There's 4 ratings type and I'd like to define a constant `rating_options` and than iterate over it to render the ratings. However, I'm not sure if I can assign the correct `setter` to each of the options.

For example, I'd like to have something like this:

```
const rating_options = [
    {
        "title": "title1",
        "id": "rating-title1",
        "setter": setTitle,
    }
]
```

And then:

```
rating_options.map(item => {
    return ( <Slider
        defaultValue={0}
        aria-labelledby={item.id}
        step={5}
        onChange={(e, newValue) => {item.setter}}
        value={item.title}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
     />
)}
```

EDIT:

```
const ContentView = ({ data, onClose, open }) => {
    const [newsworthiness, setNewsworthiness] = useState(0)
    const rating_options = [
        {
            "title": "title1",
            "id": "rating-title1",
            "setter": setNewsworthiness,
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to call `item.setter` with the `newValue` argument:

```
onChange={(e, newValue) => { item.setter(newValue); }}
```

Comment: I've edited the question and have added the part the throws the error. 
I'm getting `'setNewsworthiness' is not defined  no-undef`
EDIT: My mistake, your answer is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, sorry. Tried to tick it once you posted it but you can't accept an answer in the first 8 mins and I forgot after.